# Show current file's block hierarchy

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way in PhpStorm to show the hierarchy of where I am in the code? I'll often be placed on line 800 of some crappy top-down file and have no idea what block of the file I'm in.

For example, if my code looked like:

```
if (a) {
  // ... 200 lines of code ...
  if (unrelated) {
     // ... 200 lines of code ...
  }
  if (b) { 
     // ... 200 lines of code ...
  } else {
     // ... 200 lines of code ...
     if (c) {
        switch ($var) {
            case 'a':
               [MY CURRENT CURSOR LOCATION]
        }
     } else {
       // ... 200 lines of code ...
     }
  }
}
```

I'd want to see a summary something like:

```
if (a) {
  if (b) {} else {
    if (c) {
      switch case 'a':
```

Comment: Not available for PHP (only for HTML/XML/CSS; works at high level structure (class/method) and not logic flow (if/else) elements). The best I can suggest: 1) CodeGlance plugin (will show scrollable small code overview on a side like Sublime has) 2) use code folding to collapse not-needed-at-the-moment nodes (can be standard nodes or custom block of text) 3) if you hover over *closing* collapsing mark (that plus/minus clickable element on the left editor edge that expands/collapses the node) IDE will show you top 5 or so lines of the opening block via temp popup at the top.

Comment: Maybe there is some plugin that provides that .. but I'm not aware of such. Partially related existing tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173179 , https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22484 . Feel free to submit your own Feature request ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not available for PHP (and I'm not sure if it's present for any other supported "coding" language like JS/Java/Ruby/Python/etc).

For PHP it shows max 3 levels: Namespace, Class and Method. It does not include control/logic flow directives (if/else/for/switch)

For hierarchical/markup languages like HTML/XML/JSON/YAML/CSS (mainly pre-processors that allow nesting) and alike it will show more nodes due to their nature.

---

The best I can suggest right now that will help a bit (excluding refactoring such code as it's out of the scope and may not always be possible):

- CodeGlance plugin (will show scrollable small code overview on a side like Sublime has).
- Use code folding to collapse not-needed-at-the-moment nodes (can be standard nodes or custom block of text).
- If you hover over closing collapsing mark (that plus/minus clickable element on the left editor edge that expands/collapses the node) IDE will show you top 5 or so lines of the opening block via temp popup at the top -- good to identify what is the closest "branch" you are in.

---

Partially related existing tickets:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173179
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22484

Feel free to submit your own Feature Request ticket at [PhpStorm's Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI).

The possible issue with implementing this might be the expected complexity of the "if" conditions (most obvious case) -- quite often it will consist of 2+ conditions that might be quite lengthy (e.g. occupies 2+ lines). Problem arise with "how to display it in that small breadcrumbs area that is available".